# Insertar calculo en excel

Tags: excel

me gustaría saber como es posible añadir esta operación y que en esa celda me muestra el resultado de esta operación

```
541.0741-(33.121*A1)-(10.2824*B1)-(38.5734*C1)-(90.4374*D1)
```

he puesto el = delante pero siempre me da error.

Gracias,

Comment: Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Esto no es una pregunta acerca de programación o herramientas relacionadas a ella.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu separador decimal? Si es la coma, sustituye los puntos por comas porque si no Excel lo interpreta todo como un texto.

Comment: Perdón si la pregunta no es estrictamente de programación, estoy haciendo unos cálculos de inteligencia artificial con python, pero una parte la hago con excel y pensé que aquí podría resolver este problema.


si, en el excel son , ahí hay puntos ya que he copiado la linea de jupyter notebook.

Muchas gracias de todas formas.

Comment: @IgnacioFlorido comparte el error e indica la celda en la que esta colocada la formula. Es posible que tengas una referencia recurrente por estar referenciando en la formula la celda en donde quieres poner la formula. Para evitar suposiciones es mejor proporcionar mas detalles en la pregunta.